# Is there a method in E4X to convert a XMLList of primitive data types into an Array similar to Array.join()?

Tags: javascript, xml, actionscript-3, e4x

Is there a method in E4X to convert an XMLList of primitive data types into an Array?

For example, the Array class has a join method that converts an Array into a string and delimits each item with a comma using `join(",")`. Is there a way to do something similar with an XMLList?

Example:

```
var xmlList:XMLList = new XMLList();
xmlList[0] = "Hello";
xmlList[1] = "World";
var myItems:String = xmlList.join(","); // there is no join method in E4X
var anArray:Array = myItems.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to do what you are looking for, is to convert your `XMLList` object to an array an then use `Array.join()` like this :

```
var xml:XMLList = new XMLList();
    xml[0] = 'hello';
    xml[1] = 'world';

trace(xml.toXMLString().split('\n').join(','));     // gives : hello,world
```

Here of course you have to put the right line break (`\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`) according to your OS.

You can also use use `XMLList.prototype` to add the `join()`function :

```
XMLList.prototype.join = function(sep:String = ','):String {
    var str:String = '';
    for(var i:int = 0; i < this.length(); i++){
        str += this[i] + sep;
    }
    return str.slice(0, -1); // the String.slice() is used to remove the last ','
}

trace(xml.join(','));   // gives : hello,world
```

I tried just to give you some manners to do what you want.

Hope that can help.